# Constant memory in PGI Fortran complier on CUDA

Tags: cuda, fortran, pgi

When I am trying to specify a constant variable with another constant variable, the  PGI compiler gives this error:

> PGF90-S-0519-More than one device-resident object in assignment.

The code is as follows:

```
module var
  use cudafor
  implicit none
  integer,constant :: a,b
end  
program main
  use var
  implicit none
  a=1
  b=a+1
end
```

However, if I use b=a or b=a+0 instead of b=a+1, no error is reported.

Comment: How is `a` a constant variable? The constants you show are `b` and `c`

Comment: Also, are you *sure* trying `b=a` works? I think you should get the same error.

Comment: How can your code possibly compile? `a` isn't defined anywhere and you have `implicit none`. That should be an automatic compilation error

Comment: I know the attribute "parameter" but not the attribute "constant". Is it specific to PGI ?

Comment: @FrancoisJacq: It is a specific attribute in PGIs CUDA fortran dialect (maps to a logical memory space in the GPU)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I've corrected the error. a and b are constant variables in the sample code.

Comment: I think this may be a limitation of the way PGI converts your fortran code into the underlying copy-to-symbol API needed to populate these variables in device code.  My suggest would be to define another ordinary integer variable `ah` and do something like `ah = 1` ... `a = ah` ... `b = ah + 1`

Comment: What is about `integer,constant :: a=0,b=a+1`?

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks! I have considered your method before. But I am transplanting a complicated fortran code to cuda fortran. Now I have many variables declared in a module, some variables are read from txt files, others are calculated using these variables, and I want to use all of them in both host code and device code. The problem is there are many variables to be read from files, is there some way to avoid defining ordinary variables like that in your answer?

Comment: @Serenity Thanks. I have tried your code. The PGI complier returned "pgf90-s-0087-non-constant expression where constant expression required".

Comment: I agree with @RobertCrovella that this issue is a  `a limitation of the way PGI converts your fortran code into the underlying copy-to-symbol API`

Comment: @Ross I'm sure that if I use b=a or b=a+0 instead of b=a+1, no error is reported.